# Excel - Index-Match with duplicate ids, need row with min date greater than date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get the ID associated with a user ID, but the reference table I am pulling from is historical and effective dated. However, I need to pull the MINIMUM End Eff. Date that is GREATER THAN my row's source date, and instead of grabbing the date, I need to get the ID that is associated with that date's row.

For example:

[image: [Example]

Ideal ID Value for the top row would be 11420078, as 1/23/2019 is the min value that is greater than the source date 6/15/2018 that is associated with that user (x). The source dates shown are simply examples and are much more varied in real life.

I am running on Excel 2013 version. As there are dates involved, I can't accomplish my normal method of concatenating the values to make a composite key, especially since I am not looking for exact matches from the reference table but rather the ID of the date that is the MIN date GREATER THAN my row's date.

I have tried Index-Match with IF, but I am getting N/A values and not sure what's going wrong. I am not an experienced user with Index-match, and am having trouble applying non-exact examples to my current situation.

Edit: Per advice given by Scott, I have modified the query to be as such:

```
=INDEX($R$2:$R$9120,MATCH(MIN(IF(($P$2:$P$21986=M2)*($Q$2:$Q$21986<=L2),L2-$Q$2:$Q$21986)),INDEX(($P$2:$P$21986=M2)*($Q$2:$Q$21986<=L2)*(L2-$Q$2:$Q$21986),0),0))
```

Though it is no longer resulting in NA, it is now giving me the max value'd effective dated row for each ID, rather than the MIN that is GREATER THAN my Source Date field. For example, UserID x is getting a value of 12360373, where it should be getting a value of 11420078.

Comment: Are you confirming the formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode?

Comment: Yeah - still results in #N/A

Comment: try this: `=INDEX($R$2:$R$9120,MATCH(MIN(IF(($P$2:$P$9120=M2)*($Q$2:$Q$8504<=L2),L2-$Q$2:$Q$8504)),index(($P$2:$P$9120=M2)*($Q$2:$Q$8504<=L2)*(L2-$Q$2:$Q$8504),0),0))` let me know if it works, still an array formula.

Comment: Still getting #N/A for that one as well. Could it be an issue with the date compare? Just not sure even where to begin to fix it.

Comment: Missed it, the ranges must be the same size.  you have two different sizes.

Comment: That appears to have fixed my #N/A problem (I arbitrarily extended the reference data with some junk rows) but it appears that now each userID is simply taking the max EffDt available, instead of the MIN that is GREATER THAN my L column value (Source Date). 

Ex:

UserID x has 12360373 assigned as the value now, though 11420078 is the correct value I want it to pull.